# How can return data in javascript from SSE flask

Tags: javascript

I am sending data from python Flask (as Server Sent Event) but cant `return` this data from the function.

if print to `console.log` it works but if try to return it it says `undefined`

```
 let eventSource = new EventSource("/listen");

      function getData() {

        eventSource.addEventListener("online", function (e) {
          data = JSON.parse(e.data);
          let station = data.station;
          let finalData = data.data;
          console.log(finalData);
        });
      }
getData();
```

`finalData` is what to return to use it in stream graphics so changing `console.log(finalData` to `return finalData` shows `undefined` in console

Comment: Your `getData` needs to return a promise. `async function getData() { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ...; resolve(finalData)})}` Then you can use `console.log(await getData())`

Comment: @JuanMendes async functions return promises, the `return new promise` is unneeded.

Comment: should i use `let eventSource = new EventSource("/listen");` inside my function and use await for it?

Comment: @evolutionxbox `async` functions means it wraps values into Promises so you don't need to do `return Promise.resolve(value);` However, in this case, I need a custom promise that resolves after an event has fired so this is required. Just like anything else where some data is available in a callback that is not already a Promise callback.

Comment: @JuanMendes ok, but either way, putting async in front of a function which returns a promise is unneeded.

Comment: It's not strictly needed, but it signals to the user of your function that it returns a Promise.